# AutoMapper Ignore() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

AutoMapper keeps throwing an error that states I have unmapped properties( CustomerId, CreateDate, UpdateDate).  I'm trying to retrieve results from my database but for some reason it thinks these fields aren't being set.  I just want the error to disappear for the meantime, so I tried to set Ignore() on those 3 fields, however, I'm still getting the error.

My startup.cs is where I initialize: **Project.Api startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ....
    services.AddAutoMapper();
    ....
}
```

I use dependency injection set within my BaseService class: **Project.Service BaseService.cs**

```
protected readonly Context Context;
protected readonly IMapper Mapper;
protected BaseService(Context context, IMapper mapper)
{
    Context = context;
    Mapper = mapper;
}
```

I'm setting AutoMapper within a standalone class: **Project.Api DomainProfile.cs**

```
public class DomainProfiles : Profile
{
    public void CustomerProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CreateDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdateDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerShort, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerShort))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.RecordStatus, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RecordStatus));
    }
}
```

and calling it within my service: **Project.Service CustomerService.cs**

```
public CustomerService(Context context, IMapper mapper) : base(context, mapper) { }

    protected override DbSet<Customer> EntitySet => Context.Customer;
    protected override Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> SingleEntityPredicate(int id)
    {
        return entity => entity.CustomerId == id;
    }
    public async Task<ServiceDto<CollectionDto<CustomerDto>>> ReadAll(CollectionQueryParametersDto queryParameters)
    {
        var statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        var errorList = new List<string>();

        // Database work
        var customers = await EntitySet
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ApplyQueryParameters(queryParameters)
            .ToListAsync();

        var dtos = customers.Select(c => Mapper.Map<CustomerDto>(c));

        // Create JSON objects
        return dtos
            .WrapInCollectionResponse(statusCode, errorList);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `customers` in the second code block?  It is declared with `var`, so we don't know for sure.

Comment: The mapping configuration is correct. Can we see how you initilized your configuration ? Mapper.Initialize method ?

Comment: @ps2goat, customers is a list of models.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I've added my startup.cs where it's initialized and my base service for DI

Comment: Do you define your Profile into the same project as the Startup.cs file ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Yes, let me add my project definitions too.

Comment: I suspect it isn't using your mapping profile.  If you set a breakpoint in the profile code, does it execute?

Comment: @Amy, hey, you're absolutely right.  The AutoMapper documentation lists "When your application runs, Automapper will go through your code looking for classes that inherit from “Profile”, and will load their configuration. Simple!" which is what I'm doing, so I'm not 100% sure what to do at this point.

Comment: I figured it out, answer coming shortly

Comment: @expenguin Ah!  Sneaky!  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was that my DomainProfile wasn't set as a constructor.  In order to solve this, I had to change the CustomerProfile method name to DomainProfiles to match the class name and drop the void and it instantly worked.

**FROM**

```
public class DomainProfiles : Profile
{
    public void CustomerProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CreateDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdateDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerShort, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerShort))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.RecordStatus, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RecordStatus));
    }
}
```

**TO**

```
public class DomainProfiles : Profile
{
    public DomainProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CreateDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdateDate, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerShort, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerShort))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.RecordStatus, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RecordStatus));
    }
}
```